# qwinsta /server in vb.net Display result in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net

It is necessary to execute the batch file command -

```
qwinsta /server:NamePC
```

and display the result in a DataGridView.

I'm using the following code:

```vb
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim p As New Process
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c qwinsta /server:" & TextBox1.Text & ""
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
        p.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(866)
        p.StartInfo.StandardErrorEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(866)
        p.Start()
        Dim Result As String = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd
        If Result.Length < 1 Then
            MsgBox(p.StandardError.ReadToEnd)
            Exit Sub
        End If
        p.WaitForExit(3000)
        SplitOutput(Result)
    End Sub

    Sub SplitOutput(ByVal text As String)
        Try
            Dim source() As String = Split(text, Chr(13))
            For i = 0 To UBound(source)
                Dim r() As String = source(i).Split(New Char() {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                DataGridView1.Rows.Add(r(0), r(1), r(2), r(3), r(4), r(5))
                          Next
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
```

But the output procedure in the DataGridView does not work correctly. It displays only the title of the result.

Most likely I'm not splitting the line correctly. What could be wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to use `cmd.exe`. However, on 64-bit Windows, "qwinsta.exe" only exists in `%windir%\System32` - not in `%windir%\SysWOW64`.

If your application is running as 32-bit on 64-bit Windows, it's necessary to use `Sysnative` in the path:

```
Dim qwistaPath As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir"), "Sysnative", "qwinsta.exe")
```

If your application is running as 64-bit on 64-bit Windows (or 32-bit on 32-bit Windows), use the following:

```
Dim qwistaPath As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir"), "System32", "qwinsta.exe")
```

Try the following:

```
Private Sub GetQwinstaInfo(Optional arguments As String = Nothing, Optional encoding As System.Text.Encoding = Nothing)
    Debug.WriteLine("Is64BitProcess: " & Environment.Is64BitProcess.ToString())

    Dim qwistaPath As String

    'environment variable windir has the same value as SystemRoot
    'use 'Sysnative' to access 64-bit files (in System32) if program is running as 32-bit process
    'use 'SysWow64' to access 32-bit files on 64-bit OS
    'on 64-bit OS, 'qwinsta.exe' only exists in %windir%\System32 - not in SysWOW64

    If Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem AndAlso Not Environment.Is64BitProcess Then
        qwistaPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir"), "Sysnative", "qwinsta.exe")
    Else
        qwistaPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir"), "System32", "qwinsta.exe")
    End If

    Dim psInfo As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo(qwistaPath)

    psInfo.Arguments = arguments 'arguments
    psInfo.CreateNoWindow = True 'don't create a window

    If encoding IsNot Nothing Then
        psInfo.StandardErrorEncoding = encoding
        psInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = encoding
    End If

    psInfo.RedirectStandardError = True 'redirect standard Error
    psInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True 'redirect standard output
    psInfo.RedirectStandardInput = False
    psInfo.UseShellExecute = False 'If True, uses 'ShellExecute'; if false, uses 'CreateProcess'
    psInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden

    'create new instance and set properties
    Using p As Process = New Process() With {.EnableRaisingEvents = True, .StartInfo = psInfo}
        'subscribe to events (add event handlers)
        AddHandler p.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf P_ErrorDataReceived
        AddHandler p.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf P_OutputDataReceived

        'start
        p.Start()

        'begin async reading for both standard error and standard output
        p.BeginErrorReadLine()
        p.BeginOutputReadLine()

        'wait until the process is finished before continuing
        p.WaitForExit()

        'unsubscribe from events (remove event handlers)
        RemoveHandler p.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf P_ErrorDataReceived
        RemoveHandler p.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf P_OutputDataReceived
    End Using

    'ToDo: add desired code

End Sub

Private Sub P_ErrorDataReceived(sender As Object, e As DataReceivedEventArgs)
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data) Then
        'ToDo: add desired code
        Debug.WriteLine("error: " & e.Data)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub P_OutputDataReceived(sender As Object, e As DataReceivedEventArgs)
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data) Then
        'ToDo: add desired code
        Debug.WriteLine("output: " & e.Data)
    End If
End Sub
```

**Usage** - Example #1:

```
GetQwinstaInfo()
```

**Usage** - Example #2:

```
GetQwinstaInfo(arguments:="/server:myServerNameOrPCName")
```

**Usage** - Example #3:

```
GetQwinstaInfo("/server:myServerNameOrPCName", System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(866))
```