# Can't run Notepad from vb.net and I don't know why

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have an issue with a desktop app that is driving me crazy. I'm using vb.net in VS17 on Windows 11. My app needs to run notepad without passing it any parameters. In all my other apps `Process.Start("notepad.exe")` just works, but in this particular app it fails! I have also tried using Shell - and even on passing it the full path to the notepad executable it fails with "file not found" even after I checked that it does exist - and I can't figure that out either. Weird stuff.

I have done the hard work of creating the full and proper path to the executable (and I check that it really DOES exist), but the Process.Start call fails and returns this error "The remote procedure call failed". Here is my code.

```
Dim NPadExe As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows) & "\notepad.exe"
Try
    If File.Exists(NPadExe) Then
        Process.Start(NPadExe)
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(NPadExe & " could not be started:" & vbCrLf & ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End Try
```

I know this is junior school stuff. I've done it uncountable times before. I really need a pointer here. It seems as if this particular project is missing some or other reference or config, but I can't figure out what. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could it be permissions on the "Windows" folder? The error itself is normally linked to the "Remote Procedure Call". This service should be set to Automatic, and it should be started. I am guessing here as the code would normally run as intended so it feels more environmental related, less code related.

Comment: I agree with what you say. However, the exact same code works in another project on the same machine using the same compiler. That rules out enviromental issues for me.

Comment: I think I found the issue? Looks like a Windows 11 something. Copied the project to a Windows 10 machine, loaded it into VS17 and ran it. Notepad loaded as expected. No changes to code. Now what now? How does one bypass this? Make your own notepad maybe?

Comment: Further confirmed this by installing the app on one of my VPS machines running Windows Server 2016 Datacenter. No problem there either. So, it look like Windows 11 is the guilty party after all.

Comment: I've not used Windows 11 yet so unsure of the standard setup. If the executable is there it feels more like permissions on the "Windows" folder. I'm also seeing a few things around installing "Notepad" as it appears to be an optional feature, although that feels odd to me as I suspect it comes with the OS by default. Try running the VB application in "administrator mode": https://mobitek-system.com/blog/2020/06/how-to-run-vb-net-code-as-an-administrator/

Comment: Win 11 installed notepad as one would expect. I have not yet discovered where this is optional. I don't want to mess with windows folder permissions just yet. At least I know why the error happens. I'll make a plan to work around it for now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does it work if you use `CStr(Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\text\shell\edit\command", Nothing, Nothing)).Replace(" %1", "")` to get the location of the default text editor?

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70924974/qwinsta-server-in-vb-net-display-result-in-datagridview/70927338#70927338

Comment: @Andrew. Thanks for the suggestion and code example. Your code points to me to C:\Windows\System32\Notepad.exe on my Win 11 machine but the call to Process.Start("C:\Windows\System32\Notepad.exe") still fails with "The remote procedure call failed". Works on Win10 and Server 2016 with no problem.

Comment: @RayE Maybe that copy of Windows 11 is slightly broken. [Use the System File Checker tool to repair missing or corrupted system files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files-79aa86cb-ca52-166a-92a3-966e85d4094e) could help fix it. Keep running "sfc /scannow" until it comes up clean; I like to do a restart between fixes.

Comment: @Andrew. Thank you. Did that. One run. Came up all clean and no errors. I have spent way too much time on this issue so I made my own workaround. I only needed notepad to convert copied formatted text to plain ascii. To ensure that my app can never produce this error I created a form that uses a VB.Net textbox to do the same, so problem solved - but still the original issue remains unsolved.