# vb.net launch command from terminal

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to launch a cmd line from terminal in vb.net;
the command is located in folder C/commands/commandName and takes 2 parameters so that at the end I would write on the terminal this line:
`commandName arg1 arg2`

I also need to see what the prompt is returning so it has to stay opened
I've tried

```
Private Sub btnCreateWp_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCreateWp.Click
        Dim command As String
        Dim path As String
        Dim arg1 As String
        Dim arg2 As String
        path = C:\command\commandName
        arg1 = arg1
        arg2 = arg2
        command= path & " " & arg1  & arg2
        Shell("cmd.exe /k" + command)
End Sub
```

but it doesn't work as expected

Comment: `Process.Start`

Comment: does this code work at all?

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70924974/qwinsta-server-in-vb-net-display-result-in-datagridview/70927338#70927338